# How to improve the following database query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am running Ruby on Rails 3.1. I am querying the database *in order to retrieve article objects that have **not** category relationship with a user* and I am trying to improve the following code:

```
article_relationship_ids =
  User.article_category_relationships
  .uniq_by{|article_category_relationship| article_category_relationship.article_id}
  .map(&:article_id)

user.articles.where("articles.id NOT IN (?)", article_relationship_ids)
```

**How can I improve the above code?**

*P.S.*: Is my "retrieving approach" "logically" correct to make what I would like?

Comment: What's wrong with it? Why do you want to improve?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - I am pretty sure that there is something to improve, mostly for performance reasons. For example, the `uniq_by` method runs after the query is performed and, maybe, there is a way to make that at "database level" so to load less records... *how?*

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to explicitly optimize for performance when not knowing how the given code actually performs. Run actual benchmarks, and if the code is in fact a bottleneck, then optimize.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - BTW: How can I "estimate" if the code is a bottleneck? That is, what I have to "see"/"make"?

Comment: @Backo: you shouldn't "estimate", you should measure.

Comment: @Backo: I use [this service](http://newrelic.com/). It's not an actual profiler, but it helps me make my apps fast nevertheless.

Comment: I updated the question with a *P.S.* ...

Comment: To elaborate on what @SergioTulentsev said, I also use NewRelic, and even the free local development version is sufficient for finding some performance problems. Of course nothing is a substitute for your real production data and traffic conditions, and if performance matters than NewRelic (and the other similar services) are worth it unless you decide to roll your own measuring solution.

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - You said: "Run actual benchmarks, and if the code is in fact a bottleneck, then optimize". I'm pretty sure that my code will be a bottleneck in a short time.

Comment: @Backo You'd be amazed at some of the code I've seen in production, uncached and unoptimized, that performs with acceptable performance. Most of our optimization worries go into migrations that transform multi-million record tables that could take hours if done wrong. That said, I think probably the biggest performance issue here is that it's not all actually a query. In general, if you can do it in SQL, then *do it in SQL*. It's much better at doing what it does than Ruby is at doing what SQL can do (if that makes sense).

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Thanks for your patience. So, my issue is not a "real"/"urgent" issue at this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fetch your ids without further processing on the ruby side:

```
article_relationship_ids =
  User.article_category_relationships.select(:article_id).uniq
```

Comment: [the guides suggest otherwise](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields).  But if it doesn't work for you perhaps you have an older AR which doesn't understand. You could try `User.article_category_relationships.select(:article_id).group(:article_id).map(&:article_id)`

Comment: I am using `activerecord (3.1.1)` which should be one of the most recent.

Comment: #select will return an array of User objects with an only an `id` attribute in each object. Not an array of integers, as you might expect.